# Opera not styling my HMTL5 input placeholder

Tags: html, css, placeholder

This is really ugly. Any work-around on how to style the opera placeholder? I got the normal html5 placeholder and some css. Opera just doesnt seem to get it...

Comment: Can you post your HTML in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Comment: @Adam Simpson http://jsfiddle.net/zWkYg/

Comment: I don't see a difference in Opera versus Chrome. What platform are you using Opera on?

Comment: @Adam Simpson the text should be much darker in Opera. Im using Windows 7

Comment: Strange, on my mac the colors appear the same across browsers.

Comment: @Adam Simpson this is indeed very strange.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to format input placeholder text for the Opera browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694669/how-to-format-input-placeholder-text-for-the-opera-browser)

Answer (score 0):

Opera doesn't support styling the placeholder text yet.You can see a discussion about that here [How to style the  placeholder in Opera.](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1279012)